# ui.router + spring security - redirect upon required log in

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm building an MVC web application using spring-security for securing my app and angular.js as clent side framework.

ui.router changes the content of the page depanding on the selected state.
The problem starts when a user tries to select page referring to a page he lacks privilages to access, spring returns the login page, and ui.router inserts the login page to the body of my page.

What I would actually like to do, is redirect to the login page if login is required instead of inserting it to the current page.

How can I acheive that?

Comment: It seems you have to disable the authentication requierement in `spring` for that particular page.

Comment: But the page SHOULD be only accessible to authorized users, unauthorized users shouldn't basically get the option navigate there, but in case for example a user session expires, he may have the button referring to that page already displayed, but should be prompted to login before accessing it.

Comment: Have you tried `$location.path('login')`? You need to inject `$location` for that, obviously.

Comment: I'll read the documentation and check if it can solve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I created two different angular modules, and each module had his own routing.

the two angular modules are:

1) loginModule (with his own ui-router configuration, es. login, retrieve password, forgot password and so on...)

2) securedModule: for the authenticated part

i created two main pages that are also the entry point for each ui-router

/signIn    ->   signIn.html  -> (loginModule)   -> ui-routing for login
/secured   ->   secured.html -> (securedModule) -> ui-routing for secure

now you can configure un your spring configuration and assign /signIn as login page
and path /secured as authenticated.

here it is my spring security configuration:

```
 .antMatchers("/secured").hasAuthority("SP_LIGHT")
 .and().formLogin().loginPage("/signIn")
```